# ServiceChannel in the Faulted state exception when passing a large array through tcp cannel

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, nettcpbinding

Here's the code I'm using to start the server:

```
        ServiceHost svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

        var tcpbinding = new NetTcpBinding();
        //remove limits on the max array size
        tcpbinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
        tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
        tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        tcpbinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;

        svh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), tcpbinding, location);

        // Check to see if the service host already has a ServiceMetadataBehavior
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = svh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
        // If not, add one
        if (smb == null)
            smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        //smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        svh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        // Add MEX endpoint
        svh.AddServiceEndpoint(
          ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
          MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(),
          location+"/mex"
        );

        svh.Open();
```

here's the modified client app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8666/myservice" binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMyService"
            contract="VMyService.IMyService" name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="badasscomputing\menkaur" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

here's the test client code:

```
var r=client.GetResult(26);
```

where GetResult returns object array. When the array is small, it works without any problems, but when I'm trying to pull through a string array of 3 126 309 items (strings, in this case representing web page urls), I'm getting following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException was unhandled
Message=The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfFaulted()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at apiDemo.NS.IMyService.GetResult(UInt64 taskId)
   at apiDemo.NS.MyServiceClient.GetResult(UInt64 taskId) in D:\Users\menkaur\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\myProject\apiDemo\apiDemo\Service References\MyService\Reference.cs:line 1456
   at apiDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Users\menkaur\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\myProject\apiDemo\apiDemo\Program.cs:line 190
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

InnerException:

It looks like this comes from a large array size being transmitted, but I removed any limits to the array size I could find.

Is there anything that I have missed or does this come from an other direction?

Comment: Can you post the InnerException?

Comment: Passing 3 million strings in one go is just not a very good idea. Redesign it.

Comment: you're probably right. I seem to have hit upon what .net's tcp protocol can do

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to change [MaxItemsInObjectGraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.maxitemsinobjectgraph.aspx). The fact aside that as Henk Holterman points out that passing 3 million strings is probably not the best of ideas.